# how to increment values in ms word using add-in in visual basic

Tags: vba, ms-word

'I am trying to increment a value in ms word using add-in in visual basic.
I am  using this code:

```
    If (count = 0) Then
        Selection.Range.Text = count + 1

    Else
        count = count + 1
        Selection.Range.Text = count 
    End If
```

when i run this code the value instead of incrementation another new value is being added.

The o/p i am getting is only '1'
please help me out with this.I need values to be incremented but not added again.

Comment: i am using nested if;

Comment: Can you restate this part of your question?  I don't follow what you are saying here. "when i run this code the value instead of incrementation another new value is being added."

Comment: when I click on the button it is  printing a value '1' on the screen and when i clicking it again another '1' is being printed on the screen after the previous '1'. I need the '1' to be changed as '2' when i click on the button second time.

Comment: That is a variable scope issue.  Each time you enter a sub or function the variables local to it are recreated.  You can put your count variable at the top of your form or module above all subs and functions. That will make it global to that particular form or module. Then the function will increment how you expect.

Comment: There's not enough code here to debug this.  I'm guessing you never change the value of `count`: it will remain zero.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MathewD its working :D :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a variable scope issue. Each time you enter a sub or function the variables local to it are recreated. You can put your count variable at the top of your form or module above all subs and functions. That will make it global to that particular form or module. Then the function will increment how you expect.

```
Private Count as integer

Sub SomeSub()
    count = count + 1
    Selection.Range.Text = count 
End if
```

In the above code, the first time SomeSub is called it will be one, the second time it is called it will be 2, then 3...

EDIT:
Here is the OP ended up with that works for them.

```
Dim count As Integer
Friend Sub RangeFormat11()
    Dim document As Word.Document = Me.Application.ActiveDocument
    Dim Selection = Me.Application.Selection
    If (count = 0) Then
        Selection.Range.Text = count + 1
        count = count + 1
    Else
        Selection.Range.Text = count + 1
        count = count + 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Selection.Range.Text = "[" + count + 1 + "]"   is this line correct?   i need to add paranthesis before and after the number.

Comment: In VBA & will separate text from variables and the + is to do the math.  Selection.Range.Text = "[" & Count + 1 & "]" I think is what you are looking for. Although I think + will concatenate strings also but try to use them right.

Answer (score 0):

this is new code i used:

```
Dim count As Integer
Friend Sub RangeFormat11()
    Dim document As Word.Document = Me.Application.ActiveDocument

    Dim Selection = Me.Application.Selection


    If (count = 0) Then
        Selection.Range.Text = count + 1
        count = count + 1


    Else

        Selection.Range.Text = count + 1
        count = count + 1


    End If

End Sub
```